# Step -1 skips the loop altogether

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

My `For` loop keeps skipping when I try to use the `Step -1`

```
Dim locRow as Integer, lastRow as Integer, i as Integer
locRow = 1
lastRow = 10

for i = (locRow + 1) to lastRow Step -1
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(i,1)) Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.delete
    End if
Next i
```

When I get to the `For` line, it skips the loop part completely.  If I remove `Step -1`, then it works, but I have to add `i = i - 1` to my `If()` statement.  That's okay I guess, but I'm curious as to why the step backwards won't work.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: How will `i` (starting at `2`) ever reach `lastRow` (`10`) if you step down?

Comment: @Bond - hahaha, oh wow. Got it!  Just have to reverse the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments:

```
Dim locRow as Integer, lastRow as Integer, i as Integer
locRow = 1
lastRow = 10

for i = lastRow to (locRow + 1) Step -1
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(i,1)) Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.delete
    End if
Next i
```